# C# - DataAdapter Fill Error - Hangs

Tags: c#, fill, freeze, dataadapter

If an INT value in DB is in millions, the DataAdapter "**FILL**" function hangs even if there's a Timeout in place. How should I handle that?

For a time being I have typed-cast INT to VARCHAR to solve the issue but its a bad practice.  INT value in millions should be a normal thing.

Comment: what does 'typed-cast INT to VARCHAR' mean?

Comment: converted INT to VARCHAR

Comment: how to do you convert, what are the steps?

Comment: Have you tried changing it to `bigint`. If so, is the result still the same?

Comment: I did it in SQL, so "CONVERT(varchar(15), ID)"

Comment: its not an DB issue, its a C# issue, FILL is an internal function which does not allow override,

Comment: Then try SqlDataReader instead of SqlDataAdapter

Comment: DataReader won't work if there are multiple columns with same name & if there are multiple sub queries executing in single query. DataAdapter is the key.